# Why I insert double/float column into Cassandra by hector and got incorrect value int database

Tags: java, floating-point, cassandra, hector

I have Some question about Hector Insert double/float data into Cassandra

```
new Double("13.45")------->13.468259733915328
new Float("64.13") ------->119.87449
```

When I insert data into Cassandra by hector

```
TestDouble ch = new TestDouble("talend_bj",
        "localhost:9160");
String family = "talend_1";
ch.ensureColumnFamily(family);
List values = new ArrayList();
values.add(HFactory.createColumn("id", 2, StringSerializer.get(),
        IntegerSerializer.get()));
values.add(HFactory.createColumn("name", "zhang",
        StringSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get()));
values.add(HFactory.createColumn("salary", 13.45,
        StringSerializer.get(), DoubleSerializer.get()));
ch.insertSuper("14", values, "user1", family, StringSerializer.get(),
        StringSerializer.get());
StringSerializer se = StringSerializer.get();
MultigetSuperSliceQuery<String, String, String, String> q = me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory
        .createMultigetSuperSliceQuery(ch.getKeyspace(), se, se, se, se);
// q.setSuperColumn("user1").setColumnNames("id","name")
q.setKeys("12", "11","13", "14");
q.setColumnFamily(family);
q.setRange("z", "z", false, 100);
QueryResult<SuperRows<String, String, String, String>> r = q
        .setColumnNames("user1", "user").execute();
Iterator iter = r.get().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    SuperRow superRow = (SuperRow) iter.next();
    SuperSlice s = superRow.getSuperSlice();
    List<HSuperColumn> superColumns = s.getSuperColumns();
    for (HSuperColumn superColumn : superColumns) {
        List<HColumn> columns = superColumn.getColumns();
        System.out.println(DoubleSerializer.get().fromBytes(((String) superColumn.getSubColumnByName("salary").getValue()).getBytes()));
    }
}
```

You can see 13.45 but I get the column value is 13.468259733915328

Answer (score 0):

You should break the problem in two.  After writing, IF you defined part of your schema OR use te ASSUME keyword on the commandline cli, view the data in cassandra to see if it is correct.  PlayOrm has this EXACT unit test(which is on PlayOrm on top of astyanax not hector) and it works just fine....Notice the comparison in the test of -200.23...

https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/blob/master/input/javasrc/com/alvazan/test/TestColumnSlice.java

Once down, does your data in cassandra look correct?  If so, the issue is on your reading the value in code, otherwise, it is the writes.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I have check the result in database, it is right. When read the record get wrong result.